# Customize Wowza player interface

Tags: html, chat, live-streaming, wowza

Is it possible if we modify the interface of the wowza player? like adding some elements like image or some real time interaction such as texts from chat system

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://www.wowza.com/docs/getting-started-with-wowza-player#create-a-custom-wowza-player-with-wowza-player-builder, there are a small set of features that be customized by modifying the embedded `<script>` tag.

Regarding image addition, you can add images at the beginning and end of a video via the `posterFrameURL` and `endPosterFrameURL` keys.

Regarding text addition, you can also add a title and description (via similarly named keys), but there's nothing out-of-the-box for realtime text addition/insertion.